# T-SQL select sum of each year, and forecast next year

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a pretty simple table with:

```
Date, kWh
```

It's got about 4 years of data.

How can I produce a result set like:

```
Year, Result
2010, 123211
2011, 123213
2012, 123211
2013, xxxxxx
```

Where xxxx is a forecast for the year.

The forecast would combine the sum of the dates in 2013 so far, added to an average kWh multiplied by the days remaining in 2013.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have a data point per day, or are there random gaps or duplicates?

Comment: NOTE: to project the total for 2013, we need the average day for the previous years, not the average from 2013.

Comment: Please clarify this: the average across *all the previous years* or just across the *immediately preceding year*?

Answer (score 1):

This will calculate projected use correctly with leap years. As you can see, the leap year calculation takes more logic than the rest. Since the projection comes closer as the year progresses, then the whole year has passed, "Projected" shows actual use.

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]) year, SUM(kWh) * 
  (365 + ISDATE(CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, [DATE]) AS char(4)) + '0229')) / 
  COUNT(kWh) Projected
FROM readings
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, [Date])
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/99066/5).

To make the average count over multiple years, the query needs to be modified a little;

```
WITH average AS (SELECT AVG(kWh) kWh FROM readings)
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, a.[Date]) year, SUM(a.kWh) + AVG(b.kWh) *
  ((365 + ISDATE(CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, a.[DATE]) AS char(4)) + '0229')) -
  COUNT(a.kWh)) Projected
FROM readings a, average b
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, a.[Date])
```

This uses a cte to calculate the average to use it later in the query.

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26eed/3).

Comment: However, if all the operands are integers, it's probably better to do multiplication first, then division.

Comment: @AndriyM True, I switched it around in the answer/fiddle just in case the asker's table is INT based.

Comment: Thats not working.  The years that have passed, already have complete data sets so are not projected.  The projected year is just 2013.

Comment: @user1745767 Only days that have no data are projected. If a previous year has data for all 365/366 days, the number displayed is the total, not a projection.

Answer (score 0):

Assume every year has 365 days, certainly not true...

```
select Datepart(YEAR,[Date]) as [Year],
           case when Datepart(YEAR,[Date]) = Datepart(YEAR, getdate()) 
        then  365*Avg(Kwh)
        else  SUM(Kwh) end as TotalKwh
    from table_1
    group by Datepart(YEAR,[Date])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yous should make two queries. First one is a simple group by YEAR and the second is one line information query about the last year, days left, average kWh. Then juts LEFT JOIN these tables and you will get what you want.

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1277/4)

```
with t1 as
(
select 
       DATEPART(YEAR,[Date]) as Year,
       sum(kWh) SumKWH
from t
group by 
DATEPART(YEAR,[Date])
),
t2 as
(
select max(DATEPART(YEAR,[Date])) as MaxYear,
       AVG(kWH) as AverageKWH,
       DATEDIFF(DAY,max([Date]),
       CAST( CAST(max(DATEPART(YEAR,[Date])) as varchar(4))+'-12-31' as datetime)
                ) DaysLeft

from t
  )
select t1.YEAR, 
t1.SumKWH+ISNULL(AVERAGEKWH*DAYSLEFT,0)
from t1 
left join t2 on (t1.Year=t2.MaxYear)
order by t1.YEAR;
```

Comment: DATEFROMPARTS is not supported on my SQL 2008 R2, sorry.

Comment: @user1745767: I've changed SQL and demo to support Sql Server 2008. Please check it out.